# Why pycharm reports "can not find reference 'isoformat'" in line 6

Tags: python, json, datetime

I'd like to encode datetime when using json.
Since json doesn't support datetime type, I follow some suggestion to recontruct a subclass.
But pycharm reports:

> can not find reference 'isoformat'" in line 6

i.e, the 1st elif clause.

Why and how to solve it?

```
import datetime
class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.timedelta):
            return (datetime.datetime.min + obj).time().isoformat()
        else:
            return super(DateTimeEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Comment: Could you share, what kind of data are you trying to encode?

Comment: just a datetime obj, like datetime.now()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly are you missing, but your code works for all 4 cases:

- `datetime`
- `date`
- `timedelta`
- regular type, e.g. `str`

Here is what I'm running:

```
import datetime
import json


class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.timedelta):
            return (datetime.datetime.min + obj).time().isoformat()
        else:
            return super(DateTimeEncoder, self).default(obj)


data = {
    'dt1': datetime.datetime.now(),
    'dt2': datetime.date.today(),
    'dt3': datetime.timedelta(4),
    's': 'test'
}

print(json.dumps(data, cls=DateTimeEncoder))
```

Prints:

```
{"dt3": "00:00:00", "dt2": "2014-12-28", "dt1": "2014-12-28T01:03:36.332005", "s": "test"}
```

Tried on Python 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried and found it caused by duplicated importion.